# How can I include double quotes in a SWI-PL command line argument?

Tags: arguments, command, line, quotes, swi-prolog

Given the code a2.pl:

```
%% prolog (swipl) command line arguments
%% swipl -s a2.pl -t a --quiet -- "b" "c" "D"
%% which outputs to screen: ['D']

writeln1(Term) :-
    term_to_atom(Term,Atom),
    writeln(Atom),!.

a:-
current_prolog_flag(argv, AllArgs),
AllArgs=[_,_ | Args],
writeln1(Args),halt.
```

How can I make my query `swipl -s a2.pl -t a --quiet "b" "c" "[[v,b],":-",[[[n,=]]]]"`
which returns

```
['[[v,b],:-,[[[n,=]]]]']
```

return

```
[[v,b],":-",[[[n,=]]]]
```

?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the following method could be used to process the term, transforming it to a list, calling a2.pl's a predicate and then transforming it back to a term.

```
%% term_to_atom([[v,b],":-",[[[n,=]]]],B).
%% B = '[[v,b],":-",[[[n,=]]]]'.

%% ?- string_atom(A,'[[v,b],":-",[[[n,=]]]]').
%% A = "[[v,b],\":-\",[[[n,=]]]]".

%% swipl -s a2.pl -t a --quiet "b" "c" "[[v,b],\":-\",[[[n,=]]]]"
%% ['[[v,b],":-",[[[n,=]]]]']

%% ?- term_to_atom(A,'[[v,b],":-",[[[n,=]]]]').
%% A = [[v, b], ":-", [[[n, =]]]].
```

Comment: I will add a way to save and read from file the output of a2.pl in order to perform the last transformation back to a term in the next few days.  I don't want to use shell's output because I will use the idea with a SWI-PL algorithm that uses complex structures that I can't get the output from without printing it to a file and aborting, which gives the fail exit value, stopping it from returning output in shell.  Instead, I will write to a file and access it after the shell command has failed.

Comment: I discontinued the algorithm using the shell and file commands, because I decided it was too complicated.